# global variable is null after volley request

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm new on android studio, probably it is a simple mistake.
I want to set a color after a volley request, but my color variable is null.
I'm sure volley is returning the color.
why my color is null after my volley request?

I have this code:

```
    public class MyClass extends AppCompatActivity {

            private static Context context;
            public static String color;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            this.context = getApplicationContext();
            getColor();
            ...
        }

   public void getColor() {
   <--volley Queue-->
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                color = response; // ??????????????????????????
            }
        },
             new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Log.d("Error.Response", response);
                    }
                }
        );
        mRequestQueue.add(strReq);
    Log.w("erro: ", color); // color here is null?????????????? why??
}//getcolor()
}class
```

should I use get/set? anyone could give me an example?

Answer (score 3):

This is an asynchronous call. The log statement will execute before the result is delivered to the listener. Therefore, if you inspect the variable immediately after the call it will most likely be still `null`.

Comment: Change your program logic to not expect an immediate result.

Comment: "immediately after" is misleading

Comment: how can i halt my main thread to wait until my global parameters are loaded?

Comment: @Uday you don't want to halt the main thread. Instead, handle the result asynchronously as soon as it arrives in the `onResponse` callback.